# Correct handler postdelay time

Tags: android, runnable

I'm facing an issue about executing something at a specific time. My app has an `Runnable` class that executes a method at a specific time. The problem is that sometimes the `Runnable` needs 4000 ms instead of 3000 ms to execute. Is there a way to correct this ?

The code:

```
private Handler myhandler;

//onCreateMethod
myhandler = new Handler();


//runnable class        
    private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {     
            methodToExecute();
            myhandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);  
                     }
                 };
```

Comment: could you post your code ?

Comment: no. Android is not a realtime os

Comment: so actually, what is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that I'm making some kind of logger. Each X seconds application should write something in file. Each row in file should have a time when data is saved. Time is in HH:mm:ss format. I noticed that sometimes difference between times are not 3 second but 4 seconds. So I think than runnable is not so accurate. It is not problem if difference is 100 ms, 200 ms... but 1000 is problem.

Comment: try myhandler.postAtTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need more precision, do not use Handler.postDelayed, but rather use a Timer

Anyway, as stated in the comment, android is not realtime os, but you should get more precision, like between 2900 and 3100 ms.

For instance :

```
Timer.schedule(timerTask, 3000);
```

Comment: a Timer wont help much

Comment: Why ? It will be more precise than the Handler, which has a longer loop

Comment: ok it can help but only when you dont need to interact wirh UI thread, otherwise there is no sense to use Timers

Comment: It doesn't interact with UI. It just reading values from variables at the specific delay.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it works fine with Timer (thanks @Yves Delerm):

Here is the solution if someone need it one day:

```
private Timer myTimer;
private int TIMERINTERVAL = 3000;

// inside onCreate
myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        myMethod();
    }}, 0, TIMERINTERVAL);



 private void myMethod()
 {
      // Some code
 }
```